# Scheme program to return positive numbers in a list only returns t/f

Tags: scheme

I made this program to iterate through the numbers in a list and only return the positive numbers. The logic seems to be correct but it's returning `#t` or `#f` based on whether it's positive or not.

How do I get this to return the actual number? It's supposed to skip over the negative numbers.

```
(define (new-pos-iterator L)
  (let ((head L))          
    (lambda ()                   
      (if (null? head)  
          #f                  
          (let ((currN (>= (car head) 0))) 
            (set! head (cdr head)) 
            currN)
      )
    )
  )
)
```

`(define pos (new-pos-iterator '(4 -1 -3 6)))`

So this example should return a 4 when called and then a 6 when called again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does what you wrote it as, exactly.

The change is straightforward:

```
(define (new-pos-iterator L)
  (let ((head L))          
    (lambda ()                   
      (if (null? head)  
          #f                  
          (let ((currN ;; (>= (car head) 0)))   ;; was performing test too early
                       (car head)))
            (set! head (cdr head)) 
            ;; currN            ;; was returning the test result unconditionally
            (if ;; perform the test _now_:
               (>= currN 0)
                ;; is non-negative, return it
                _______    ;; fill the blanks
                ;; otherwise negative, skip it
                _______ )  ;; fill the blanks
            )))))
```

How to skip it? Well we already did, so the question becomes, how to return the first positive member in the remaining list? <sub>(well, non-negative, but who cares for the off-by-one errors, right?).</sub>

Don't we *(kind of)* have a function doing it for us already?

If we name it, we can call it again. And again, as needed.

---

So, what to call there? `(new-pos-iterator head)`?

No, not that. It would return the generator procedure which needs to be called -- the result of that `(lambda () ...)` form. *That* is what needs to be named; called inside itself; and having it named, we just return is as the result from `(new-pos-iterator ...)`.

Of course that naming -- *binding* -- needs to be *recursive*.

*`letrec`* does that.

Otherwise, we could code this with a named loop, which uses `letrec` internally.

Comment: So for the first blank I put currN..second node I put (new-pos-iterator head)) and it works except when it encounters a negative number it prints out "#<proceedure>" instead of just skipping the number

Comment: right, for the first; for the second, not `(new-pos-iterator head)`, no. it returns the generator procedure which needs to be called -- the result of that `(lambda () ...)`. that is what needs to be named, called inside itself; and having it named, we just return is as the result from `(new-pos-iterator ...)`